# I got an error when I try to load existing design in vue-email-editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

here is my function

editorLoaded() {

```
    this.$refs.emailEditor.editor.loadDesign(this.emailJson);

    console.log('editorLoaded');
```

},

Answer (score 0):

To load design in editor, you need to pass whole design object in editor on load like:

```
 this.$refs.emailEditor.editor.loadDesign( 
  // add your design object here, which you recived while exporting OR saving design using unlayer functions
 )
```

Note: This function must be called after editor is loaded

[Official Doc Reference](https://docs.unlayer.com/docs/load-and-save-designs#load-design)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av3ed.png)